# When a product is added to cart, can we remove the same product from the search results during the same session?

Tags: cart

when a product is added to cart by a user, can we remove that same product from the search results during the same session if user is already having it in his cart and pursue it's search journey?
Thank you!
Ludovic

I just need help on that